# Run script file from other script file in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, executable

I have several Octave script files that run tests, named test_1, test_2, etc. I want to have a script file that will run all the tests, without having to switch all the test_n files to function files. I've tried several variations on this:

```
#!/path/to/octave -q
addpath('/path/to/directory/containing/all/scripts/');

source(test_1.m);

source(test_2.m);
```

but I always get "error: invalid call to script /path/to/directory/containing/all/scripts/test_1.m".

(I've tried source_file(), run(), and just having the filename alone on the line.)

Is there any way to run script files from a script file in Octave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
source test_1.m
```

or

```
source('test_1.m')
```

instead.

Your syntax implies `test_1` is a struct variable and you're trying to access a field called `m`

Same with the `run` command (in fact, `run` simply calls `source` under the hood).

You can also call the script directly, if it's on the path. You just have to make sure you don't include the `.m` extension, i.e.

```
test_1
test_2
```

Comment: To make sense of the error you're getting: Octave is telling you "ok, there's a file 'testo.m' in the path, which means there's a script / function called `testo` available for me to use. But I have no idea why you're telling me to access a member `.m` from it. That's no way to call a script or function! They don't even have members!"

Comment: By the way. If you intend your code to also be compatible with matlab, avoid the `source` approach, since this is octave-specific. `run` and calling a script directly (if on the path) are both fine.

Comment: @EvanGunter also have a look at [http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/command-vs-function-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the name of the included script, without .m extension on a separate line.

Lets have for example script 1: 'enclosed.m'
and script 2: 'included.m'. Then enclosed.m should look like:

```
% begin enclosed.m
included;      % sources included.m
% end encluded.m
```